# Eclipse for Robot Framework (java version) project: how to run specific tags?

Tags: eclipse, robotframework, ui-automation

My project uses Maven to reference all needed libraries, so I don't even need to manually install robot framework (I just included markusbernhardt's **Selenium2Library** as a dependency in pom.xml):

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I can run my tests as Maven Install or using a Run Configuration for Maven:

[image: Run as Maven Install]

[image: Run configuration]

However, I don't know how to tell robot framework that I want to run tests tagged with certain tags. I don't run robot framework from a command line as I don't have robot framework installed in my machine, I'm only using it as a maven dependency, so I can't run `python -m robot.run --include tag`.

I tried adding `--include tag` as a Parameter in the Run Configuration but it's being ignored.

Is there a way to send this tag parameter to robot within Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Just found out how! Leaving info here in case it helps someone else:

It's all in pom.xml:

Add a `<properties />`first-level element (within `<project />`) with a property name of your choosing and the tag you want to run, like this:

```
<properties>
  <robot-tag>mytag</robot-tag>
</properties>
```

Then, in the plugins section, within the robotframework-maven-plugin `plugin`
element, add this:

```
<configuration>
  <includes>
    <include>${robot-tag}</include>
  </includes>
</configuration>
```

That's it. The Run Configuration doesn't need to be changed. And the project can also be ran as Maven Install.

This is what my pom.xml looks like now (stripping out the  element and project-specific info like groupID, artifactID, etc):

```
  <properties>
    <robot-tag>debug</robot-tag>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>${robot-tag}</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```